# Window event listener is not firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events, event-listener

I created window listener which has worked properly. After some time, I don't know when exactly, window listener stopped working. Resize event also doesn't work. I have no idea what can be a reason of that it is not working.

```
  mounted () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.test)
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.test)
  },
  methods: {
    test () {
      console.log('test')
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**

I created listener inside main app vue component, still not working.

```
<template>
  <div id="application" class="" style="height: 200vh">
<!--    <router-view/>-->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.test);
  },
  methods: {
    test () {
      console.log('test')
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $route: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(to) {
        document.title = this.$t(to.meta.title) || 'Some Default Title'
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT2**
When component is mounted, function is running twice from event listener, no less no more
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeiUq.png)

Comment: `After some time` - so, if you load your page, and wait "some time" this just stops working?

Comment: This part of code seems just right. I guess we need more details in order to diagnose the issue

Comment: By 'After some time' I meant few days ago it was working, now it doesn't work at all

Comment: Can you confirm, that the component was mounted correctly and no other JS errors interfere? What you show us here looks good.

Comment: Any single error, just some warnings (language variables). I'm suprised cuz it looks good and it was working, but today I recognized it stopped working and I'm trying find out why.

Comment: The reason could be that the scroll container ist not the body element. I also experienced, that some events are missing if the app is inside an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

HTML tag was setted at 100vh, so window was not really moving. Child inside was scrollable.